# Increasing Scalability of a microservice based system

Tags: architecture, microservices, scalability

I am using KAFKA to get the data from a source.
I want to know that if I increase the number of component serially in the microservice architecture, will it make it more scalable? Or just increasing the number of KAFKA consumers of same component type will increase it? 
PS: Sorry for any mistake, I am posting a question for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to read kafka documentation or some book like kafka definitive guide of o'reilly to better understand. But basically in kafka you have consumer groups and all consumers (services), that share the same consumer group will collaborate, this means that the events consumed by one of those services will not be consumed by others, so this way you can parallelize de consumer process.

When you create more instances of the same service, this is what happen because both services will share the same configuration, so both will share the same consumer group.

On the other hand, if the two services instead belongs to different consumer groups the will process all the events independently

Answer (score 0):

Each topic-partition is consumed by a single thread in each consumer group. If you want to increase throughput you need to partition that specific topic which is 1 by default. If you partition a topic, you can consume the topic in parallel with separate threads for each partition. Those threads might be in different deployables, this depends on your architecture, there is no restriction here.

When you partition a topic you may need to do some extra work both on producer side and  consumer side in order to provide data consistency between those microservices. There may be messages that need to be consumed in the order that they have produced. In such cases, you need to send related messages to the same partition which enforces them to be consumed in the order.